# Using Hiphop for PHP extension development

Tags: php, php-extension, hiphop

Hiphop converts PHP into C++ code, did anyone used it for PHP extension development?

I have found following link to write PHP extensions using C++ 
http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486-Wrapping-C-Classes-in-a-PHP-Extension

I want to write some PHP classes and convert them into C++  and use it in PHP extension.

Please let me know if anyone did that  and also any thoughts are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the point of HipHop is to bypass PHP's Virtual Machine known as Zend Engine.

In order to create a PHP extension, you have to hook into the Zend Engine.

So if HipHop bypasses the execution done by ZE, I don't see how it'd be possible to create a PHP class that gets translated to C++ one that would then be used to create an extension.

HipHop doesn't convert PHP **source code**, it converts the **BYTE** code. It's a huge difference, if it were the former.. would there be a need for using another language? :)