# Compile PHP source code into extension (.so / .dll)

Tags: php, compilation, php-extension

Is there a way to make one of my PHP API libraries compiled into PHP extensions?
I don't want my client see the source code of that PHP API.

I searched and found the same, BUT with Cython (of Python): [How to protect and compile python source code into a .so library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436484/how-to-protect-and-compile-python-source-code-into-a-so-library)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort-of equivalent in PHP-world is "HipHop for PHP", which takes PHP code, translates it into C++, and compiles it.  This, of course, adds dependency requirements to any web server that's using your library.

Linky: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki

Comment: based on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646276/using-hiphop-for-php-extension-development, I don't think hiphop could create such extensions

Comment: I wouldn't see why you couldn't compile your "protected/API" PHP code into C++ using HipHop and then write a simple wrapper that wraps this code to expose it to PHP again for others to use in PHP?  Having used HipHop on some projects myself, I don't see why this wouldn't work... it's no different than creating an API for any other C++ program.  (That said, I wouldn't want to think of the dependencies this API might have now...)